# jQuery change doesn't fire when radio inputs are clicked programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some inputs of type="radio":

```
<div style="margin:10px;"><input type="radio" name="cei" id="clike" /><label style="margin:0 10px" for="clike">like</label></div>
<div style="margin:10px;"><input type="radio" name="cei" id="ccomment" /><label style="margin:0 10px" for="ccomment">like</label></div>
<div style="margin:10px;"><input type="radio" name="cei" id="clink" /><label style="margin:0 10px" for="clink">like</label></div>
```

and a change function do do some stuff when each of them is checked:

```
        $('input:radio[name="cei"]').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).next().html() == 'link') 
        $('#clink-val').removeAttr('disabled');else $('#clink-val').attr('disabled','disabled');
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).next().html() == 'Multiple Choices') 
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.multiplechoices-item').slideDown(); else $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.multiplechoices-item').slideUp();
});
```

Up to here the code works perfectly.
now as the radio buttons above are generated via server-side code and might be only 2 radios for a user and 5 of them for another user. so I want that the first radio be checked. I tried:

```
 $('input:radio[name="cei"]').first().attr('checked','checked');
```

and

```
 $('input:radio[name="cei"]').first().click();
```

while both of the above codes sets the checked attribute of the first radio but for none of them the `$('input:radio[name="cei"]').change()` doesn't fire.

Comment: You should fire the "change" event since that's what you bound to.

Comment: $('input:radio[name="cei"]').first().click(); will trigger the change. It is working fine for me. check this https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6510/

Comment: @dan08 So I should set checked value and also fire the change? why change doesn't fire while the checked status changes?

Comment: I would. Like so: `$('input').attr('checked', true).change()`, because firing `change` won't toggle the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to trigger the change event

```
$('input:radio[name="cei"]').first().prop('checked',true).change();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fire the change event after you change the value.

```
$('input:radio[name="cei"]').first().attr('checked','checked').change();
```

```js
  $('input:radio[name="cei"]').change(function(){
  console.log('changed');
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).next().html() == 'link') 
        $('#clink-val').removeAttr('disabled');else $('#clink-val').attr('disabled','disabled');
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).next().html() == 'Multiple Choices') 
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.multiplechoices-item').slideDown(); else $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.multiplechoices-item').slideUp();
});


 $('input:radio[name="cei"]').first().attr('checked','checked').change();
 $('input:radio[name="cei"]').eq(1).attr('checked','checked').change();
 $('input:radio[name="cei"]').eq(1).attr('checked','checked').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin:10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="cei" id="clike" /><label  for="clike">like</label>
</div>
<div style="margin:10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="cei" id="ccomment" /><label  for="ccomment">like</label>
</div>
<div style="margin:10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="cei" id="clink" /><label for="clink">like</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$('input:radio[name="cei"]').change(function(){})
```

try

```
$('body').on('change','input:radio[name="cei"]',function(){})
```

dinamically added element need an event listener like this